# Launch iPhone app from link in email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, url-scheme

I've been trying out the URL schemes in the iPhone SDK and I have got my application to launch using a custom URL scheme like "myap://Dosomething" but that is not really practical for what I want. Is it possible to register a scheme somehow that would allow links in emails like "http://www.mydomain.com/" to launch my application, like app store links and youtube links do?

Comment: How did you end up solving this? I have the same need, I want to send our users email with regular http links, and if the user has our app installed I'd like it to launch our app when the user clicks the link. If they don't have the app installed I'd like it to just go to the url with mobile safari.

Comment: were you able to implement this without a redirect?

Comment: it's impossible to do without a re-direct as you cannot (unfortunately) have http :// my-custom-url-scheme to launch the app automatically.. Annoying that this is the case!

Answer (score 7):

If you want the link to be clickable in Mail you have to use an `http://` link which will launch Safari. This means you should create a page on a webserver somewhere that return an HTTP 303 redirect (See Other) with your `myApp://` url. This should cause Safari to launch your application. If that fails you can try a `<meta>` redirect, and as a last resort a standard `<a href="myApp://">Click me</a>` link.

Comment: It would be a good idea to look at the browser that's making the request on your web-server and re-direct only if you detect it's a mobile browser.. There are numerous ways to do this depending on your web server technology..

Answer (score 0):

To do that you would have to register and host that domain and set it up to redirect to the URL scheme. How to set up the redirect depends on what web server you're running. Why do you think myapp:// is impractical?

Comment: A meta redirect is probably sufficient (perhaps even better as an error page can be shown if the app isn't installed)