# Is it possible to launch an iPhone app from a text message?

Tags: iphone

This question:

[Launch iPhone app from link in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228982/launch-iphone-app-from-link-in-email)

suggests that it's possible to launch a particular iPhone application from a link in an email.  Is it possible to include an app-launching link of this type in a text message, so that the reader has the option of pressing it (and launching the app) in the same way that they can call a phone number in a text message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the iOS application programming guide section [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW50).

1. Add a row to your Info.plist (right-click the root item and select Add Row) and give the new row the key `URL types`.
2. Open up the item that is added as a child of that row and set the `URL identifier` to something like `com.yourcompany.product`.
3. Add a child row to Item 0 and give it the key `URL Schemes`
4. Set the value on that row to something unique. Maybe your app name (no spaces, just letters).
5. Implement the application:handleOpenURL: in your application delegate in case you want to actually look at the URL.

Comment: NOTE: The app has to be already installed, though, for this to work.

Comment: And then, to call the app, send a text-message containing your scheme, `myapp://...`.

Comment: RTFM, huh? :) Thanks for the simple breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this? It takes 5 minutes to connect a url scheme to your app. Then just send yourself a text message with a link.